# how to access images in sequence using loop in openCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Guys i ran into a problem regarding accessing images in sequential order. i have images whose names change with incrementing number i.e. cube_0.jpg, cube_1.jpg, .... and so on. Now i want to access each image one-by-one and show. 
Following is my code that i am playing with since 2-days and don't know how to handle this situation or what is wrong with this problem.

```
ostringstream s;

for (int fileNumber = 0; fileNumber<=40; fileNumber++)
        {
            s<<"\"cube_"<<fileNumber<<"\.jpg\""<<endl;  

            string fullfileName(s.str());
            images[i] = fullfileName;

        }


        stringstream ss;
        cout<<"file name"<<images[0]<<endl;

        for (int file = 0; file<41; file++)
        {

            string str = images[file];
            cout<<"str "<<str<<endl;
            img_raw = imread(ss.str(), 1); // load as color image           Error
            cout<<"Done"<<endl<<"size"<<img_raw.size();
            system("pause"); 

        }
```

This code runs fine till it gets reached to "img_raw = imread(ss.str())", now this line is basically hindering me from accessing file. Since imread requires "string& filename" therefore i performed stringstream operation but nothing is working!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors.

Your `stringstream ss` is empty. You declared it but did not fill with any values. I am pretty sure you meant `imread(str, 1);` instead of `imread(ss.str(), 1);`

In the first **for** loop, you are continuously printing filenames to ostringstream, so it goes like this:

> **0:** "cube_0.jpg\"
>
> **1:** "cube_0.jpg\""cube_1.jpg\"
>
> **2:** "cube_0.jpg\""cube_1.jpg\""cube_2.jpg\"
>
> ...

so the ostringstream just grows and grows. ostringstream needs to be declared in the loop to be cleared for every iteration.

**Edited code:**

```
string images[41];
Mat img_raw;

for (int fileNumber = 0; fileNumber < 41; fileNumber++)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "\cube_" << fileNumber << "\.jpg" << endl;  

    string fullfileName;
    ss >> fullfileName;
    images[fileNumber] = fullfileName;
}

for (int file = 0; file < 41; file++)
{
    cout << "Loading " << images[file] << endl;
    img_raw = imread(images[file], 1);

    if (!img_raw.empty())
    {
        cout << "Successfully loaded " << images[file] << " with size " << img_raw.size() << endl; 
    } 
    else
    {
        cout << "Error loading file " << images[file] << endl;
    }

    system("pause"); 
}
```

Comment: i had already followed this approach but upon your recommendation, i did it again but no change. when i cout<<str; it shows the result "cube_204" including double quotes but when i cout the size of img_raw i.e. cout<<"Done"<<endl<<"size"<<img_raw.size(), the line next to where the word "Error" is written, It shows [0 0]. which means it is not being read by "imread".

Comment: See edited simplified code. Works fine for me. If size is [0 x 0] then your image doesn't exist or it is not in the right folder.

Comment: O great, Man! It works for me too now. I was getting the same problem as you identified for the case of ostringstream. when i changed my code from ostringstream to stringstream, it worked. Another problem that i noticed is that i was using ss<<"cube"<<fileNumber<<"\.jpg" incorrectly! Thank you so much!